handletype(NetworkError) not available
I'm attempting to retry a URL call on a network failure error using the 'cockatiel' package.
The code that I wrote is as follows:-
import { retry, handleType, ExponentialBackoff} from 'cockatiel';
    const response = await retry(
                handleType(NetworkError),
                { maxAttempts: this.maxAttempt, backoff: new ExponentialBackoff({ maxDelay:this.maxDelayMs, initialDelay: this.initialDelayMs }) }, 
                ).execute() as HttpResponse;
            return response;
        }

I cannot locate a package that I may import in order to utilize "NetworkError."
Where do I import 'NetworkError' from?
The cockatiel package version is "3.1.3" while my node version is "v18.20.1"

I think NetworkError from the docs is just an example and you need to define it yourself. For example:
class NetworkError {}

const handleNetworkErrors = handleType(NetworkError);

const retryPolicy = retry(handleNetworkErrors, {
  maxAttempts: 3,
  backoff: new ExponentialBackoff(),
});

handleRequest = async (req, res) => {
  const data = await retryWithBreaker.execute(async () => {
    try {
      return await fetch("/");
    } catch {
      throw new NetworkError();
    }
  });
  return res.json(data);
};


